# GWT project won't start

Tags: macos, gwt

My GWT project "runs", I think, but it doesn't ever show the UI. It just sits there.  How can I get it to show the UI, which was the whole reason I used GWT. 
When I used older GWT, the UI displayed right away without my having to do anything. I have run the same application in the latest GWT before, but it no longer shows the UI. It just sits there.

Comment: look in the browser console for errors.  If using Chrome, press Ctrl+Shift+J or Option+J

Comment: The best place now to ask for GWT questions is to join https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt